# Differential Equation with Laplace operator

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $r = r(s)$ be a twice differentiable function.

I need a function $u = u(s)$ such that $u'' = r''/r$, where $r''$ is the second derivative of r.

Comment: What is $\Delta u(s)$?

Comment: If u has a single variable, i'm pretty sure it is the same as u''. I dont know why they wrote like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know $r(s),$ you can just integrate $r''/r$ twice to get a solution for $u.$  There will not be any usable general formula for $u$ in terms of $r$ though.  For example, if $r$ is just a quadratic function of $s,$ the solution for $u$ involves inverse tangent, logarithm, and square roots.